# Как отменить автоматический стиль для конкретного элемента?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Есть стиль

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    ****
</Style>
```

То есть применен ко всем кнопкам на форме. Но вот беда, стиль этот влияет и на стиль для кнопки внутри `DatePicker`. Как можно это исправить? Просьба, задать стилю `x:key` не предлагать. Нужно решение, которое не потребует применения однообразного кода ко всем кнопкам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Обновление.** @iRumba в комментариях предложил ещё более простое решение, в котором не требуется писать в App.xaml. Просто в ресурсах той области, где нужно восстановить стиль по умолчанию, пишем следующее:

```
<Style TargetType="Button"/>
```

Пример:

```
<Window x:Class="..." ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- перекрываем стиль для кнопки -->
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button>У этой кнопки стиль перекрыт</Button>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Padding="2">
            <!-- восстанавливаем исходный стиль -->
            <Border.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button"/>
            </Border.Resources>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock>В этой области перекрытие отменено</TextBlock>
                <Button>У этой кнопки снова стиль по умолчанию</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Картинка с результатом внизу.

---

Очень просто. Давайте сохраним стиль кнопки по умолчанию и дадим ему имя. Для этого положим в `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonDefaultStyle"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Теперь в окне можно делать как-то так:

```
<Window x:Class="..." ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- перекрываем стиль для кнопки -->
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button>У этой кнопки стиль перекрыт</Button>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Padding="2">
            <!-- восстанавливаем исходный стиль -->
            <Border.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultStyle}"/>
            </Border.Resources>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock>В этой области перекрытие отменено</TextBlock>
                <Button>У этой кнопки снова стиль по умолчанию</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Получается так:

[image: style resetting]

---

**Ещё одно обновление**

Если нам нужно отменить переопределение стиля внутри любого из контролов определённого типа, это можно тоже сделать при помощи стиля!

Например, пусть у нас есть `UserControl` с кнопками:

```
<UserControl x:Class="..." ...>
    <Grid>
        <Button>I'm Button! Big Button! I like clocks!</Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Если мы используем его в нашем коде и хотим отменить перекрытие стиля для кнопки, делаем так:

```
<Window x:Class="..." ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- перекрываем стиль для кнопки -->
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Style>
        <!-- это стиль для ControlWithButtons, внутри которого... -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ControlWithButtons}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <!-- ... мы переопределяем стиль для всех внутренних кнопок! -->
                <Style TargetType="Button"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button>У этой кнопки стиль перекрыт</Button>
        <local:ControlWithButtons/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Результат:

[image: style resetting]

Comment: У вас общий стиль -- дефолтный, перекрываете вы его кастомным. А у автор наоборот: общий стиль -- кастомный, а перекрыть хочется дефолтным.

Comment: @andreycha: Почему же? Стиль в App.xaml снабжён ключом, он ничего не перекрывает. Кастомный стиль — это тот, который в `Window.Resources`, он устанавливает перекрытие внутри окна.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения. Вчитался еще раз внимательнее.

Comment: Снова выручили )

Comment: Вопрос. А можно это как то описать более универсально? Чтобы не делать у каждого контрола переопределение стиля кнопки. Ну типа в ресурсах окна прописать `<Style TargetType="DatePicker">***</Style>`. А то там нет Property Resources.

Comment: А ну да, не обязательно делать DefaultButtonStyle. Достаточно просто написать `<Style TargetType="Button"/>` :)

Comment: @iRumba: Круто! С вашего позволения, дополню ответ.

Comment: @iRumba: `Resources` есть у каждого контрола, не только у окна.

Comment: @VladD, вот именно, resources есть у каждого контрола... Так вот, стиль в ресурсах окна `<Style TargetType="Button">***</Style>` означает, что каждая Button будет использовать этот стиль. Далее, чтобы в `<DatePicker>` отменить использование этого стиля, мне нужно в КАЖДОМ из них прописать в `Resources` отмену стиля. Так вот можно ли не делать это в каждом контроле, а сделать один раз для каждого типа контролов (datepicker и, может, другие, где точно не нужен переопределенный стиль для кнопок)?

Comment: @iRumba: А, понял :) И это можно. Сейчас протестирую и напишу.

Comment: @iRumba: Готово!

Comment: Спасибо! Жаль два плюсика нельзя поставить )

Comment: @iRumba: Пожалуйста!